# RDF SPARQL Query - Find tuples that are not part of both conditions (LEFT JOIN in SQL)

Tags: sparql, rdf, blaze

Below is the data set I have:

```
:project#1   :hasRevision        :revision#1
:revision#1  :hasRevisionNumber  1 
:project#1   :hasRevision        :revision#2
:revision#2  :hasRevisionNumber  2
:project#1   :hasRevision        :revision#3
:revision#3  :hasRevisionNumber  3
:revision#1  :committed          :A1
:A1          :hasId              1
:revision#2  :committed          :A2
:A2          :hasId              2
:revision#3  :reverted           :A1
```

#### Use case:

Need to fetch attributes committed in each revision.
 - If the user asks for `:revision#1`, `A1` should be returned.
 - If the user asks for `:revision#2`, `A1` and `A2` should be returned.
 - If the user asks for `:revision#3`, only `A2` should be returned as `A1` is `:reverted` in `:revision#3`.

The closest query I could come up with is below which is not working:

```
select ?attribute ?id WHERE { 
    :project1  :hasRevision       ?revision . 
    ?revision  :hasRevisionNumber ?revNum ; 
               :committed         ?attribute . 
   ?attribute  :hasId             ?id . 
   FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?revision :reverted ?attribute } 
   FILTER ( ( ?revNum <= 3 && ?revNum > 0 ) && ?id in (1,2) ) 
}
```

#### Actual Output:

```
A1 & A2
```

#### Expected Output:

```
A2
```

I understand the issue. Not able to come up with a proper query. Can any of you please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're doing `FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?revision :deleted ?attribute} `, but why do you use `:deleted` instead of `:reverted` ? The same for `:created` instead of `:committed` - right now, the query doesn't match the data

Comment: In addition, `?revNum <= "3" && ?revNum > "0"` might lead to problems given that you compare strings here instead of numbers

Comment: that was just a typo. I tweaked the query as I couldn't put the exact scenario as in my scenario.Please check now.

Comment: 1. your data couldn't be parsed with the `#` in a prefixed name, thus I changed to `@prefix : <http://test.org/> .

:project1 :hasRevision :revison1 .
:revision1 :hasRevisionNumber  1   .

:project1 :hasRevision :revision2 .
:revision2 :hasRevisionNumber 2 .
:project1 :hasRevision :revision3 .
:revision3 :hasRevisionNumber 3   .
:revision1 :committed :A1  .
:A1 :hasId 1  .
:revision2 :committed :A2 .
:A2 :hasId 2  .
:revision3 :reverted :A1 . `

Comment: 2. your query works as expected on the data using Jena CLI tool.

Comment: While you inserted the data, "revision1" was spelled wrong. That's why!  Can you please check again. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well, it was again you who made the typo (look at the edit history before TallTed fixed everything) ... I just replaced all `#` chars. And yes, now it returns `A1` and `A2`

Comment: There is a join with ?revision within FILTER NOT EXISIT but You should use a different valiable there. E.g. when :revision1 is bound to ?revision the filer do not find a statement (:revison1 :reversed ?attribute) so the solution where ?attribute=:A1 is added to teh result set

Comment: @DamyanOgnyanov In that case, A1 will not be returned even in revision 1 or 2 as there is a "reverted" relationship exists from revision 3

Comment: @Linz you could filter out other revisions on additional criteria within NOT EXISIT, e.g. for instance, its revision number being less than or equal to the target

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of different variable in the FILTER NOT EXISIT, e.g.

```
FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?otherRevision :reverted ?attribute }
```

Edit: after the additional comment from @Linz and adding a filter to look only for revisions with smaller revison numbers.

```
prefix : <http://base.org/>
select ?attribute ?id WHERE { 
    bind (3 as ?targetRevisionNum )
    :project1  :hasRevision       ?revision . 
    ?revision  :hasRevisionNumber ?revNum ; 
               :committed         ?attribute . 
   ?attribute  :hasId             ?id . 
    FILTER NOT EXISTS { 
        ?other :reverted ?attribute . 
        ?other :hasRevisionNumber ?otherRevNum .
        filter (?otherRevNum <= ?targetRevisionNum )
    } 
   FILTER ( ( ?revNum <= ?targetRevisionNum && ?revNum > 0 ) && ?id in (1,2) ) 
}
```

Comment: In that case , A1 will not be returned even in revision 1 or 2 as there is a "reverted" relationship exists from revision 3.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround.
An object can be `:committed` and `:reverted` only once. So used `having` with aggregate function to filter based on the count of relationships from "`revision`" to "`object`" o my final query is below:

```
prefix : <http://test.org/> 

select  ?attribute WHERE { 

        :project1  :hasRevision       ?revision . 
        ?revision  :hasRevisionNumber ?revNum ; 
                   ?s   ?attribute .
        ?attribute :hasId ?id;
        FILTER ( ( ?revNum <= 3 && ?revNum > 0 ) && ?id in (1,2) )  

}  
group by ?attribute 
having (count(?attribute) < 2 )
```

Output:

```
attribute
<http://test.org/A2>
```

I would be glad if anyone could find me a better query. Thank you everyone!